# How to deal with data contained in a list of elements with different sizes to train an LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

:)

First of all, I want to apologize about my english that might not be very good since it's not my native language. Afterthat, I expose my problem :

I'm new in Python/Keras and currently, I'm working on a sequence-to-sequence problem using LSTM. Here it is : I got a dataset of a robot arm kinematics. All kinematics  have the same number of columns but different numbers of rows (rows represent time steps). I got 24 kinematic as training data and I want to feed it to an LSTM. So, I've created a list containing the 24 elements. The problem is when I want to create an LSTM, I have to specify the "input_shape" argument (according to an error that occured after running a part of code). But the thing is I don't have any idea about the value I must put on "input_shape" since my training data is a list of kinematics with different amounts of time. All I know is that I have a list with 24 elements with 76 columns each. Here is the part of code that I run :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

And here is the error that occured : `

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Pctec\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 
454, in add
    raise ValueError('The first layer in a '
ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an 'input_shape' 
or 'batch_input_shape' argument.`
```

Afterthat, I've searched a solution to the problem and found this : 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-univariate-time-series-data-long-short-term-memory-networks/

It gave me a little idea about what I should do, however, the author came up with an example where the number of time steps is known, unlike the case I'm working into.

I don't know if I gave enough details about my problem because like I said, I'm still a beginner but maybe someone can help me with this.

So, according to what should I specify the value of input_shape for the LSTM ?

Thank you :)

Comment: If the number of timesteps is varying you can put `None` in its place, i.e. `LSTM(100, input_shape=(None, 76))`.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I'll try it.